# Get the row with the max(DateTime) LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Every row in the Message table contains a DateTime. How can I get the message row with the highest DateTime (The newest date)?

I now have this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> getLastMessageByUnit(int unitId)
{
    IQueryable<Message> tempQuery = context.Message;
    tempQuery = tempQuery.Where((x) => x.Unit == unitId);

    return await tempQuery.ToListAsync();
}
```

But when I do this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> getLastMessageByUnit(int unitId)
{
    IQueryable<Message> tempQuery = context.Message;
    tempQuery = tempQuery.Where((x) => x.Unit == unitId).Max(x => x.DateTime);

    return await tempQuery.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<BackendPoCMachinelearning.Models.Message>'

Comment: OderByDescending+First

Comment: How would you do that in SQL? The same way works with LINQ

Comment: You should probably return `Task<Message>` rather than `Task<IEnumerable<Message>>` considering there is only a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by date and take the first

```
public async Task<Message> GetLastMessageByUnit(int unitId)
{
  return await context.Message
    .Where(x => x.Unit == unitId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

..and if you really need it to be in a list, add it to one (but I'd change the return type of the method) because as Johnathan Barclay has pointed out in the comments, it doesn't make sense to name a method as something that returns one item, but have it return multiple

You can't use Max, because that will just return the highest datetime (and throw away the rest of the info) similar to how `SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM t WHERE UnitId = 123` would. What you're looking for is the LINQ equivalent of `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM t WHERE UnitID = 123 ORDER BY DateTime DESC`.

The MoreLinq library has a MaxBy extension which can do a similar thing but you should be careful as to whether what it does can be translated to work in SQL.. If you're working with local data, for example, MaxBy may offer a useful performance boost because there's no point sorting a load of data only to take one item, when a "loop over it keeping track of the highest X and its associated Y you've seen" will suffice

Comment: Yep, `MaxBy` won't work well for `IQueryable`.